# Does Twitter's URL parser break URLs that contain certain strings?

Tags: twitter, url

I've been told that Twitter sometimes breaks URLs that have specific strings in them. This is the reason that Stack Exchange's tweet bots automatically shorten URLs before they're Tweeted.

But after conducting a tiny bit of experimentation, I can't seem to find a URL string that was corrupted by Twitter.

Did Twitter fix a parsing bug? Are there any strings found in URLs (on this network and elsewhere) that break URLs delivered via Twitter?

Comment: I know Twitter doesn't recognize unknown TLDs or domains like `domain.tld` or `localhost`.